# How to remove one Windows partition to install Ubuntu, but keep other partitions on drive

Tags: installation, partitioning

I'm using Windows 7 currently and would like to switch it just to Ubuntu 12.04 thus removing windows 7 completely. However, I'd like to keep the data stored in other partitions. I have 4 partitions on the hard drive, namely C, D, E and F at the moment with Windows 7 installed on C:. I would like to retain the data from all the other 3 partitions in Ubuntu. Can anyone please tell me what steps I need to take in order to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/59887/making-the-switch-windows-to-ubuntu

Alternately try http://askubuntu.com/questions/129399/if-i-delete-a-windows-drive-can-i-use-that-space-to-install-ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes...

here's how to do it-

When you boot the LIVE CD/USB for installation, you will get 3 options-

1. Erase Windows 7 and replace with Ubuntu 12.04LTS
2. Install alongside Windows 7
3. Do something else.

for your Requirement,you shold click on the 3rd option - Do something else.

That will take you to a partition table.

In the partition table you will see 4 partitions.(mostly the 1st one will be c drive)

but do remember to see the size of your windows partition (c) from windows b4 starting installation.because the size is the only thing that can help you recognise the c-drive when installing as you wont see labels like c or d there.

after you find out the windows partition,select it from the table below and click on delete..!!

That partition(and thus your windows) will be deleted.

Then select that unallocated space(which was the c drive earlier) and click on add.

Now,you can either directly make the complete partition as EXT4 for installing Linux or you can also add a SWAP partition.(It is always recomended to add a SWAP area for better performance but only if your ram is below 8gb)

If you select to add the SWAP AREA,do the following(otherwise go to the part below this sub-explaination starting from "NOW..")-

(After clicking on add)

1. Assign the space from that partition to SWAP AREA equal to double your ram.(e.g-for  1gb,swap area-2gb)
2. Select SWAP AREA from the file system drop down menu.
3. Select "Begining" in the partition positition dropdown menu.
4. Click on add.

Now, after you have added the SWAP AREA,do this-

1. Select the remaining "Unallocated space" and click on ADD.
2. Select Ext4 Journaling filesystem from the file-system dropdown menu.
3. Select "Primary" from the partition type drop-down menu.
4. Select the mount point as "/" from the mount-point drop-doen menu.
5. Select "begining" from the Positition drop-down menu.
6. Click on add.

After adding the patitions,from the table select the ext4 partition you see and tick in the corresponding chek-box(if not already ticked)

then Select INSTALL...

Comment: ok thanks. one quick question. doing this would not affect the data  that is stored on the other partitions right?

Comment: Yeah it wont.That data will remain intact.
Just for extra info,after loging into ubuntu,you will see those partitions as external devices(like a usb) so to use them,you have to mount them(i.e just click on them) every time you start the computer from the powered off state.

Comment: And a quick tip,
Select the "Install 3rd party software" and "Download updates during install" options during installation to not face problems further.It will take a bit long to install with this but it is safer and better(I assume you know how to add a DSL/Wireless/Mobile broadband connection in order to connect to the internet)

Comment: im using tata photon wireless dongle at the moment for internet. I know the installation procedure but it can be done only after installing the OS right?

Comment: The procedure is given in the answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which would make things a bit safer and easier but would require you to crawl under your desk (in case your computer is there):

- disconnect the 3 drives you don't want to erase
- boot from Ubuntu LiveCD and install in "automatic" mode (i.e. - no manual fiddling with partitions, just choose Erase Windows and install Ubuntu)
- shut down and connect the drives back.

(that is if by "four drives" you mean "four physical hard drives", not "four partitions on a single hard drive")

Comment: Im sorry I didnt write that down correctly. I have a single  drive with 4 partitions , not 4 physical hard drives.

Comment: I guess ron had mentioned it properly as to they are 3 drives on single HDD.(the lables c,d,e,f explain it)

Comment: @Nirmik: 4 physical hard drives would also have labels C, D, E and F :) I edited the original question to make it less ambiguous