# Is it easy to install Apache web server on Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: apache2, webserver

So I have decided to build a Ubuntu computer, for now I am going to dual boot with Win7, and then install apache web server. Figured I would give the whole web thing a try. 
Did some searching but didn't find something powerful enough, I will continue searching as I am sure there is a multitude of items on here... but one quick question.

Has anyone installed Ubuntu desktop, and then apache web server ?
Was it easy to do?

Comment: You want instructions for installing Ubuntu too?? here is the link...http://askubuntu.com/questions/138234/installing-ubuntu-by-replacing-windows-os-for-the-first-time/138238#138238

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Comment: goodness, i installed Ubuntu 2x on my PC, first time it only was able to read an external drive, couldn't boot to it.  So I disconnected all USB drives and booted to my CD again.... it finally saw my hd so i installed it along side windows, on a reboot.... went straight into Windows... geez a little frustrating especially since it took like 30 mins for each installation.  What the heck... bbllahhhh

Answer (score 7):

Very very very very easy. Besides installing apache by itself with

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

you can do even more since you might want to install Perl for coding on the server and MySQL for database storage. [So Ubuntu comes with a tool that can set up a complete LAMP server with 1 installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel).

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and then run `tasksel` as superuser

```
sudo tasksel
```

Choose the option LAMP installation and you will get a pre-configured(!) Apache, MySQL and Perl installation. All you need is a root password for MySQL.

---

Shorter version:

```
sudo apt-get install lampserver^
```

No more need for "tasksel" since the ^ is now used to tell "apt-get" it is a "task" that needs to be installed.

Comment: Please note that `sudo apt-get update` should be run before `sudo apt-get install ...` unless it's been run very recently. `apt-get update` doesn't *upgrade* any packages, rather it updates information about what packages are available and from what software sources, so that your system asks for and gets the right packages when you `install` or `upgrade`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Just run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install apache2` in a terminal. Or search for it in the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy.
Fire up your terminal, then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server mysql-client
```

If you don't need php5 or mysql, just type `sudo apt-get install apache2` in place of that second command,

Comment: ok good to know, but i think I will need or want to test php, and mysql out for something i got planned. thank you.

Comment: Note: This installs MySQL and PHP on top of Apache.