# Need guidance on ubuntu 16.04 lts installation. I would like to keep D and E drives from windows

Tags: partitioning

This is the device partition info:

[image: This is the device partition info]

The image shows my hdd partition chart. The one I marked as ext4 and set mount point / is the C drive from windows. Also I can't really identify the `sda1` and `sda3` what are these spaces allocated for? I would just love to install ubuntu on the C drive and replace windows. I am confused regarding what to do at this stage. Should I press install after I have set the file system as EXT4 and mount point as /. One more thing is that I can't find the delete option as it said in the post I am linking below.
[How to remove one Windows partition to install Ubuntu, but keep other partitions on drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138234/how-to-remove-one-windows-partition-to-install-ubuntu-but-keep-other-partitions)
Please guide me with the installation.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! you should clarify a bit what are you trying to do? you want to dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows or you just want to have partitions with NTFS file system for sharing.

Comment: The delete option is the `-` button left to the `Change` button. `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda3` probably contain some Windows specific information (as serial keys recovery software, etc.) if this system comes with pre-installed Windows.

Comment: The laptop supposedly came with Linux preinstalled but the vendor from whom I bought, installed win10 on it. I would like to replace win10 and have ubuntu as my primary OS.